# How to use anyof inside required anyOf jsonSchema?

Tags: jsonschema

Inside object x, it should have anyOf a,b and also should have anyOf c,d.
This is my current code which works but it doesn't seem the right approach.

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "x": {
            "type": "object",
            "anyOf": [
                {
                    "required": ["a","c"]
                },
                {
                    "required": ["a","d"]
                },
                {
                    "required": ["b","c"]
                },
                {
                    "required": ["b","d"]
                }
            ],
            "properties": {
                "a": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "b": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "c": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "d": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How to do this in a simpler way?
i.e, Object x should have (a or b) and (c or d).

Comment: `anyOf` is "one or more". Currently, you're saying the object could have a,b,c, and d. Is this what you mean, or do you intend for the `required` conditions to be mutually exclusive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Object x should have (a or b) and (c or d)

If this is precisely what you need, then you can express that with the `allOf` keyword combined with `anyOf`. Just think of `allOf` as AND, and `anyOf` as OR:

```
...
"allOf": [
  {
    "anyOf": [
      { "required": ["a"] },
      { "required": ["b"] }
    ]
  },
  {
    "anyOf": [
      { "required": ["c"] },
      { "required": ["d"] }
    ]
  }
]
```